# How to set up sending emails in IIS7 + php

Tags: php, email, iis-7

I have a dev environment in my localhost pc, and its using IIS7 and php. I want to send emails but when I try in php I get:

```
Warning: mail(): Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set() in C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Project\site\script\common.php on line 20
```

Does anyone know what is wrong?

Here is my IIS7 config:

[image]

Comment: is a smtp-Server running on port 25 on this Server? what server-Software for email you are using? did you set up your php.ini-file properly for using mail?

Comment: I have no idea how to check all that. I am new to this.

Comment: if you don't have a smtpp-Server, you could use mailenable for example, it delivers enough Features in the free Version for your testing-encironment

Comment: IIS doesn't have a build in smtp-Server, so if you are trying to send an email, IIS will try to connect to your SMTP-Server, but will fail by finding one, so no mail will be sent

Comment: by the way: php tries to connect directly to a smtp-Server, so the Settings in IIS won't have an effect as far as i know, the Settings will be made in your php.ini